# Rxjs requests with queue of webworkers in parallel

Tags: typescript, web-worker, rxjs6

I have a series of requests and 4 web workers. I want to feed the responses to the workers and as soon as worker finishes feed another response and so on. I don't want to block the requests though.

[image]

The code that I have written doesn't show any difference between having 1 or 4 workers:

```
const octrees$ = from(spatialKeys)
        .pipe(
            concatMap((spatialKey: string) => {
                console.log("REQUEST");
                return this.sgsApi
                    .getCellById(
                        sessionId,
                        volumetricModelQueryId,
                        spatialKey
                    )
                    .then(resp => resp.arrayBuffer())
                    .then(datBuffer => ({
                        datBuffer,
                        spatialKey
                    }));
            }),
            // SINGLE WEB WORKER
            // mergeMap(({ spatialKey, datBuffer }) =>
            //  this.unpackWorkers[0].unpackDat(spatialKey, datBuffer)
            // )
            bufferCount(4),
            switchMap(values => {
                console.log("UNPACK");
                return values.map(({ datBuffer, spatialKey }, index) =>
                    this.unpackWorkers[index].unpackDat(
                        spatialKey,
                        datBuffer
                    )
                );
            }),
            combineAll()
        )
        .subscribe(val => {
            const t1 = performance.now();
            console.log("COMPLETED at :", (t1 - t0) / 1000, val);
        });
```